# How to combine two sets bound by equations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, multisets

Sorry if this is worded oddly.

I have a set [27n+12] ie. [12,39,66,...]
and another set [9n+5] ie. [5,14,23,32,...]

Is there a way to combine these two sets into a single set bound by 1 simple equation easily?

[?] ie. [5,12,14,23,32,...]

Comment: Changing 9n+5 by 27n+5, 27n+14, 27n+23, you have that the set you are looking for is of the form [27n+5,27n+12,27n+14,27n+23] In general there is no "comprehensive" way to express your set. Hope I've helped you.

Comment: thank you. this should help